# S3 static hosting still showing the old version of the Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-codepipeline

We have a code pipeline that has a webhook with a git branch.

Every time a push has been made to that branch a code pipeline is triggered.

source -> build -> DeployToDevS3 -> DeployToStgS3.

This flow was working great until the last time I checked.

Now the issue is Deployment to dev s3 and stage are showing a success message and even the file within them is showing the latest modification.

The Development site is showing the updated code.
Whereas the staging site is showing the old code.

Both have a cloud front in front of them.
The stage distribution is still showing the old version if I access the domain name

Could anyone help me out of this

Comment: Do the buckets contain correct versions? If yes, then you may need to invalidate your CF cache, as it may still show cached, old version.

Comment: how do I invalidate my CF cache? But the deployment happened like 12 hours ago

Comment: The default TTL is 24 h hours. To explicitly invalidate files, there is [create-invalidation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html) API for that. Maybe this is what is happening? [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidating-objects-api) is more general info about that.

Comment: @Marcin Done. 
thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Default CloudFront TTL is 24h. To force serving new content before cache expires, you have to [invalidate the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidating-objects-api), using one of the two methods:

- Invalidate the file from edge caches using [create-invalidation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html) API call.
- Use file versioning to serve a different version of the file that has a different name.

Alternatively, for future use, one can reduce default TTL from 24h to something more suitable, e.g. 6h.

Comment: For future reference: 

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serving-outdated-content-s3/

Comment: could you help me out with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234984/aws-code-pipeline-is-failing-at-deployment-stage-by-timing-out