# Aws Code pipeline is failing at Deployment stage by timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to work my way to have a ci/cd for the Api part of the application.

I have 3 steps:

1: Source (git hub version2)

2: Build (currently has no commands)

3: Deploy(provider is code deploy(application))

Here is the screenshot of the events in code deploy.

[image] .

While creating the Deployment Group. I chose the option of downloading the code deploy provider from the option(though it was necessary).

[image]

While setting up the code pipeline chose
[image]

Felt that was appropriate.

This code pipeline has put an object into the S3 bucket for this pipeline.
Code deploy is acting on that source artifact.

Note:
We have nothing on this Ec2 image it's just a place where we have our API.
Currently, Ec2 is empty.

What would be the proper way to implement this? How can I overcome the issues I am facing.

Comment: If build does not do anything, you can fully delete this stage. What about your `appspec.yml` file for the CodeDeploy? Maybe it is incorrect?

Comment: @Marcin oh okay will remove the build step. 
Is appspec.yml necessary? Should it be part of my repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `appspec.yml` your deployment will fail. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-server):

> An AppSpec file must be a YAML-formatted file named appspec.yml and it **must be placed in the root** of the directory structure of an application's source code. Otherwise, **deployments fail**.

Comment: could you help me out with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247453/sending-sms-notification-to-multiple-phone-number-using-sns-with-boto3