# Sending sms notification to multiple phone number using SNS with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, boto3, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an event-driven notification through SMS using aws SNS.

I am trying to write a script to send a message to a single number first.
Here is my below code for that

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client("sns")
    response = client.publish(
    PhoneNumber="+91 xxxxxxxxxx",
    Message="Hello World!"
    )
    print (response)
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The thing here is I am not getting any message from this.
Could anyone help me out in achieving this use case of mine?

Comment: When you manually send message using AWS console in SNS, does it work?

Comment: yes it does. 
The format there which I am using is 91-xxxxxxxxx.
I tried the same with code. But it's not working

Comment: While printing the response the HTTPstatuscode response is 200. But I don't get any message.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: I haven't tested it. I assume sns topic or lambda permissions are set?

Comment: lambda permissions are set. 
I have set up any topic as I am trying to publish to one mobile number first

Comment: works for me. I think your phone number format may be incorrect. try removing dashes. References here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html